# Empty miniframes header in TOC frame

Tags: beamer, mini-frames

As the title suggest I would like to *keep* the background but get rid of the circles and text. Using `[plain]` for the title page is ok for me but for the TOC the frame feels out of place and thus I do *not* want to use `[plain]`.

**Edit 1:** A MWE. It contains 3 slides. All of them have this gray block, as I like it. But I do not want the first two slides to also display the circle and the text.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=x11names,compress]{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
\useinnertheme{default}

\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{fg=black,bg=black!10} 

\title{A title}

\author{Mr Z.}
\date{\today}



\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Outline}
\tableofcontents[pausesections]

\end{frame}

\section{test}
\subsection{My Test}

\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code defines an environment `nonavigation` that removes the mini frames navigation while still keeping the headline itself. To use it, include the code into the preamble of your document (i. e. anywhere between `\documentclass{beamer}` and `\begin{document}`) and enclose the frames where no navigation bar should be shown in `\begin{nonavigation} ... \end{nonavigation}`.

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{nonavigation}{\let\orig@insertnavigation=\insertnavigation\def\insertnavigation##1{\phantom{\orig@insertnavigation{##1}}}}{}
\makeatother
```

#### Explanation

To remove the mini frames navigation, the original command responsible for generating the navigation bar (`\insertnavigation`) is modified to typeset its output into a `\phantom`, i. e. to produce an empty box with the same dimensions as the original content. This is necessary as simply removing the navigation bar completely would result in undesired white space in the headline.

#### Full example

```
\documentclass[xcolor=x11names,compress]{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
\useinnertheme{default}

\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{fg=black,bg=black!10} 

\title{A title}

\author{Mr Z.}
\date{\today}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{nonavigation}{\let\orig@insertnavigation=\insertnavigation\def\insertnavigation##1{\phantom{\orig@insertnavigation{##1}}}}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}


\begin{nonavigation}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Outline}
\tableofcontents[pausesections]

\end{frame}
\end{nonavigation}

\section{test}
\subsection{My Test}

\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: title page of the example document, with headline showing no navigation bar]